# Amazon RDS: Thousands of PostGIS debugging messages appearing in my logs

Tags: postgresql, postgis, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4

I am using the PostGIS extension with a PostgreSQL in Amazon RDS. I use Octopus Deploy along with PowerShell and `psql.exe` to perform database deployments and import jobs. I run my own PostgreSQL server in my test environment, and my deployment and data imports run perfectly and don't generate any `psql.exe` debugging notices. However, when I run my data import against my RDS database, my Octopus logs are filled with thousands of messages like this one:

```
psql:C:/Windows/TEMP/tmpA924.tmp:1: NOTICE:  [lwgeom_functions_basic.c:LWGEOM_makepoint:2144] LWGEOM_makepoint called
```

It looks like all the messages are related to my scripts' usage of PostGIS types and functions.

What is the proper way to get rid of these debugging messages so they don't pollute my logs and spike my deployment server's CPU and RAM utilization? Seeing as how I am in AWS, I want to avoid network traffic at all costs. Optimally, there is some way to have the extension not generate these debugging messages at all. I'd like to avoid filtering the messages *after* they traverse the network between RDS and my deployment server.

EDIT 1: I found what I think is a [description of the `POSTGIS_DEBUG` macro](https://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/postgis/DEBUG) that is compiled into PostGIS, but obviously I don't have rights to recompile the PostGIS code that RDS is running.

EDIT 2: As a better demonstration of the verbosity of these messages, executing the SQL `select world.st_setsrid(world.st_makepoint(30, 30), 26913);` results in these messages (also note the total query runtime):

```
NOTICE:  [lwgeom_functions_basic.c:LWGEOM_makepoint:2144] LWGEOM_makepoint called
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_any_size:378] Input type: Point
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwpoint_size:286] point size = 24
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwgeom_size:420] g_serialize size = 32
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwgeom_any:677] Input type (1) Point, hasz: 0 hasm: 0
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwgeom_any:678] LWGEOM(0x2b87172b3080) uint8_t(0x2b87172b3228)
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwpoint:445] lwpoint_to_gserialized(0x2b87172b3080, 0x2b87172b3228) called
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_set_srid:78] Called with srid = 0
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:50] entered
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized:1137] Got type 1 (Point), srid=0
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized_buffer:1091] Got type 1 (Point), hasz=0 hasm=0 geodetic=0 hasbox=0
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:50] entered
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_set_srid:1455] entered with srid=0
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_set_srid:1455] entered with srid=26913
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_any_size:378] Input type: Point
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwpoint_size:286] point size = 24
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwgeom_size:420] g_serialize size = 48
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_gbox:772] returning size 16
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwgeom_any:677] Input type (1) Point, hasz: 0 hasm: 0
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwgeom_any:678] LWGEOM(0x2b87172b30a0) uint8_t(0x2b87172b3048)
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_from_lwpoint:445] lwpoint_to_gserialized(0x2b87172b30a0, 0x2b87172b3048) called
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_set_srid:78] Called with srid = 26913
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:50] entered
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:gserialized_get_type:53] skipping forward past bbox (16 bytes)
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized:1137] Got type 1 (Point), srid=26913
NOTICE:  [g_serialized.c:lwgeom_from_gserialized_buffer:1091] Got type 1 (Point), hasz=0 hasm=0 geodetic=0 hasbox=1
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_set_srid:1455] entered with srid=26913
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_is_empty:1233] lwgeom_is_empty: got type Point
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwgeom_to_wkb:710] WKB output size: 25
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwgeom_to_wkb:723] Hex WKB output size: 51
NOTICE:  [lwgeom.c:lwgeom_is_empty:1233] lwgeom_is_empty: got type Point
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:393] Entering function, buf = 0x2b87172b3530
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:395] Endian set, buf = 0x2b87172b3532
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:integer_to_wkb_buf:189] Writing value '536870913'
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:398] Type set, buf = 0x2b87172b353a
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:integer_to_wkb_buf:189] Writing value '26913'
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:403] SRID set, buf = 0x2b87172b3542
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:360] Writing point #0
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:364] Writing dimension #0 (buf = 0x2b87172b3542)
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:364] Writing dimension #1 (buf = 0x2b87172b3552)
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:ptarray_to_wkb_buf:369] Done (buf = 0x2b87172b3562)
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwpoint_to_wkb_buf:407] Pointarray set, buf = 0x2b87172b3562
NOTICE:  [lwout_wkb.c:lwgeom_to_wkb:759] buf (0x2b87172b3563) - wkb_out (0x2b87172b3530) = 51
Total query runtime: 561 ms.
1 row retrieved.
```

Comment: I found stackoverflow.com/questions/3530767/…, but I really want to treat the problem at its source (PostGIS outputting debugging messages) rather than go update all my client code to disable notices.

Comment: But this is Amazon RDS. I can't access the underlying server, right?

Comment: oops forgot. One of the reason we setup our own servers on ec2 instances rather than relying on their stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found out the solution, but you have to change the client_min_messages threshold to be above notice, such as with:
    SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;
This will also greatly speed up the call for large geometries.